# Visual Studio (Mac) does not recognize some Unity types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-mac

I am creating a class library which needs to reference Unity-specific types like `GameObject` for example.

- I am on MacOS (latest)
- I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 for Mac [Version 8.6.2 (build 6)]
- I am using Unity 2019.3.14f1

#### My setting

In my C# project I am setting the same target .NET as the autogenerated C# project in one of my Unity projects:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Then, as instructed in the [documentation on plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html), I am referencing the DLLs:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="UnityEngineRoot">
        <HintPath>$(UnityBasePath)UnityEngine.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="UnityEngine">
        <HintPath>$(UnityBasePath)UnityEngine/UnityEngine.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="UnityEngineCoreModule">
        <HintPath>$(UnityBasePath)UnityEngine/UnityEngine.CoreModule.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="UnityEngineAnimationModule">
        <HintPath>$(UnityBasePath)UnityEngine/UnityEngine.AnimationModule.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="UnityEditor">
        <HintPath>$(UnityBasePath)UnityEditor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Where `UnityBasePath` is: `/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.14f1/Unity.app/Contents/Managed/`.

#### The problem

Everything actually compiles just fine!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Animations;

public class MyClass
{
    private UnityEngine.GameObject obj;
    private AnimationClip clip;
}
```

The class above compiles just fine.

Problem is Visual Studio IntelliSense which underlines in red most of the types I am using (making the dev experience quite painful):

> The type name 'Object' could not be found in the namespace 'UnityEngine'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

But as you can see from the code I posted, I have referenced `UnityEngine.CoreModule`! I also get this for `AnimationClip`:

> The type name 'AnimationClip' could not be found in the namespace 'UnityEngine'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'UnityEngine.AnimationModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

And there as well, module `UnityEngine.AnimationModule` has been referenced.

Comment: Do you have the latest "Visual Studio Editor" package installed in Package Manager in your project?